# Does $\omega(G)\leq k$ imply $\chi(G)\leq k$ for $n\geq 3$?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Let $G$ be a simple graph with $n$ vertices. Let $\omega(G)$ and $\chi(G)$ denotes the clique number and chromatic number of $G$ respectively. Then

> Does $\omega(G)\leq k$ imply $\chi(G)\leq k$ for $n\geq 3$?

Comment: Try a 5-cycle and see for yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, even triangle free graphs are counterexample since they can have arbitrary large chromatic number.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle-free_graph#Coloring_triangle-free_graphs

Answer (score 2):

No. For the cycle graph $C_5$, $\chi(C_5)=3$, but $\omega(C_5)=2$.
So for $k=2$, $\omega(C_5) \le k$ but it is not true that $\chi(C_5) \le k$.